# WebAPI 2.0 Post and Delete Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have two actions on the same controller, with identical routes, but separate `HttpMethod` requirements (`POST` vs `DELETE`).

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("~/api/test")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult Endpoint1()
    {
        return this.Ok("endpoint1");
    }

    [Route("~/api/test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Endpoint2()
    {
        return this.Ok("endpoint2");
    }
}
```

This is all fine -- both endpoints work when switching from `DELETE` to `POST`.

E.g.

```
DELETE /api/test = endpoint1
POST /api/test = endpoint2
```

If I separate the actions into separate controllers, it does not work anymore:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("~/api/test")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult Endpoint1()
    {
        return this.Ok("endpoint1");
    }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public class TestController2 : ApiController
{
    [Route("~/api/test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Endpoint2()
    {
        return this.Ok("endpoint2");
    }
}
```

E.g.

```
DELETE /api/test = endpoint1
POST /api/test = { "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'." }
```

Is this expected from the framework?

**EDIT:**
The exact WebAPI package version is: 5.2.3

Comment: 1. It will be a good idea to specify the version of Web API that you are using.
2. "~/" in the routes is not necessary, "api/test" works fine

Comment: Why not place all http verbs related to a controller... in one controller?

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer: 1. updated to specify version. 2. Regardless of ~ or not, the same issue occurs.

Comment: @woogy -- I do for most scenarios -- but the goal of this post is to display an issue found when not grouping them by controller, but rather action they are doing.

Comment: yes - the ~/ thing is just stylistic

Comment: looks like it is by design, I actually get a 500 when I tried your repro with a clear explanation. I do have a workaround I will post as an answer though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## What is going on

Web API 2.0 does not a allow a route to match on two different controllers. This is solved in MVC 6 (which is Web API combined framework).

## What can I do about it

First like @woogy and you say, it is not a very common pattern, so most users should just not go here (or move to MVC 6 when it goes RTM).

The root cause is that the route actually matches, the verb defined an an `IActionHttpMethodProvider` does not constraint the route from matching, and it matches on multiple controllers thus failing.

You can however define a constraint on the route, and as a side effect get a more succinct API.

## Let us get started

#### Define a verb constraint

This will constraint the route to only match the predefined verb, so it wouldn't match the other controller.

```
public class VerbConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint
{
    private HttpMethod _method;

    public VerbConstraint(HttpMethod method)
    {
        _method = method;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request,
                      IHttpRoute route,
                      string parameterName,
                      IDictionary<string, object> values,
                      HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        // Note - we only want to constraint on the outgoing path
        if (routeDirection == HttpRouteDirection.UriGeneration || 
            request.Method == _method)        
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

#### Define an abstract base class for a new attribute

```
public abstract class VerbRouteAttribute : RouteFactoryAttribute, IActionHttpMethodProvider
{
    private string _template;
    private HttpMethod _method;

    public VerbRouteAttribute(string template, string verb)
        : base(template)
    {
        _method = new HttpMethod(verb);
    }

    public Collection<HttpMethod> HttpMethods
    {
        get
        {
            var methods = new Collection<HttpMethod>();
            methods.Add(_method);

            return methods;
        }
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Constraints
    {
        get
        {
            var constraints = new HttpRouteValueDictionary();
            constraints.Add("verb", new VerbConstraint(_method));
            return constraints;
        }
    }
}
```

This class merges 3 things
1. The route attribute with the route template
2. Applies a verb route constraint to the route
3. Specifies the action method selector, so the rest of the system (like help page) recognizes it just like the `[HttpPost]` / `[HttpDelete]`

#### Now let us define implementations

```
public class PostRouteAttribute : VerbRouteAttribute
{
    public PostRouteAttribute(string template) : base(template, "POST")
    {
    }
}

public class DeleteRouteAttribute : VerbRouteAttribute
{
    public DeleteRouteAttribute(string template) : base(template, "DELETE")
    {
    }
}
```

These as you can tell are pretty trivial, and just make the use of these attributes in your code a lot smoother.

#### Finally let us apply the new attributes (and remove the method attribute)

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [DeleteRoute("api/test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Endpoint1()
    {
        return this.Ok("endpoint1");
    }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public class TestController2 : ApiController
{
    [PostRoute("api/test")]
    public IHttpActionResult Endpoint2()
    {
        return this.Ok("endpoint2");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Yishai for the extremely detailed explanation.  This does work - but will happily wait for MVC 6 :)

Answer (score 0):

[HttpDelete("DeleteEmployee/{id}")] 
public async Task DeleteEmployee(Guid id)